# When I turn off one layer it automatically turns off (disables) the other layer. How to disable this behavior?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have a problem in Photoshop CC. When I turn off one layer it for some reason turns off the other layer above (disables it), which is not my goal. How to disable this behavior?

Please, see the pictures.

Here both top layers are on:

[image]

Now I turn off the second layer from top and it automatically disables the layer above:

[image]

How to turn off a middle layer without disabling a top one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The adjustment layer is set as a "clipping mask", meaning that it is applied *only* to the layer below it. You can <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>-click between the two layers (right at the line dividing the layers). This will remove the  link relationship between the two layers.

You can also right-click (Windows) or <kbd>Control</kbd>-click (Mac) the upper layer and select `Release Clipping Mask` from the contextual menu.

Using a layer as a clipping mask is often done with adjustment layers (e.g. making things brighter, changing colors, etc.). This way, the adjustment will only be applied to the layer directly below the adjustment layer, instead of all layers below the adjustment.